# History Rewritten...By Katla Volcano

Tags: alternate-history, natural-disasters, volcanoes

In 2010, the Icelandic volcano of [Eyjafjallajökull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull) (a pronunciation guide to this will be much appreciated) had released a cloud of ash that enveloped all of Europe, a good deal of Asia and the northeastern coast of Canada, grounding all attempts at flying for months.

In its aftermath, scientists had been growing worry about something bigger--the possible eruption of Eyja's big brother, the largest volcano in all of Iceland, [Katla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katla_volcano).  There were records of Katla's eruptions dating from 1918 to 934, but in this alternate scenario, its largest eruption--VEI-6--coincided with either of the following popular watersheds:

- 476, the year the Roman Empire collapsed
- 1933, the year the Great Depression was at its worst
- December 21, 2012, the date that popular culture has marked as the Day of Disaster

If Katla unleashed its fullest potential in an eruption at either one of those dates, what would the immediate aftermath be?  And how much of history would it alter?

Comment: Did you mean 1934? Because you put 934.

Comment: No, I do mean 934.

Comment: Pronunciation guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSo_ND41-6g

Comment: Sound file with the name from Wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull-bjarmason.ogg

Comment: @JohnWDailey You just confused me because normally it goes from the oldest date to the newest.

Comment: John I would suggest you limit this to what the effect would have been on one date at a time, or maybe just ask, what would the societal ramification have been on the Roman Empire in xxx year.

Comment: Thucydides already beat you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most probable events post eruption would be a "year without summer", similar to the aftermath of the eruption of Mount Tambora in 1815, when massive quantities of ash, dust and sulphur aerosols filled the atmosphere and drastically reduced the amount of insolation reaching the Earth.

Large scale crop failures would put severe stress on any polity regardless of the time period. Indeed, the collapse of Bronze age empires, the fall of the Roman Empire and even the French Revolution have been blamed directly or indirectly on climactic shifts which affected crop growth. The farther back in the past you go, the more devastating the effects, as it is more difficult to both store mass quantities of food, and distribute it in a timely manner during periods of crop failure. In the 1930's, you could expect large scale rioting and the attraction of political mass movements like Fascism would increase as desperate people sought any source of stability in the crisis. (A little known fact is that FDR's "New Deal" was largely copied from the model of the Italian "Fascist Corporate State", so much of the machinery for a possible Fascist takeover or slide in the United States was already in place). In 2012, the situation would be somewhat easier to deal with, given global trade and the ability to move massive quantities of goods and services, but economies would be heavily strained by the extra costs, and the soaring process of food and energy (due to rising global demand) would still be enough to trigger many problems as the world's poor and even middle class were squeezed.

The lack of investment capital would also lead to a deepening economic downturn, and if the events leading to the 2008 financial crisis were in play in this time line, the global economy would be even worse off (don't forget that many of the economic numbers were already being manipulated post 2008 to try and make people believe there was a recovery, for example the BLS ignored both the labour participation rate and the people who had "dropped out" of the employment market to suggest unemployment was going down, in reality US unemployment has never fallen below 10% once those factors are added back in).

So in any scenario expect food shortages, riots, soaring inflation for food and energy and a mad scramble to move resources away from other investments to try and deal with the problem at hand. If the effects of the eruption go on long enough wars should also be factored in, as starving peoples become desperate enough to try and invade their neighbour's agricultural areas to steal the crops.